# Can Expressmapper copy to destination?

Tags: c#, mapper

I'm currently using expressmapper.

And I'm facing an issue, when i try co map an object to another one (aka destination). I get NullReferenceException, what seems to happen is when object "source" has some complexe properties (non value type) and "destination" haven't initialized them (ie: destination.MyListOfThing = null) then expressmapper throw the exception. Also when working with IList, elements don't get copied.

I'm not sure it's a "by design" behaviour, because a versatile mapping framework is one where you don't have to know anything (except from the type maybe) of the source object.

Is this a bug or something you can configure?

Edit: here are my classes definitions:

```
    public class MapSource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public MapSource Parent { get; set; }
        public List<MapSource> Children { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator int(MapSource src)
        {
            return src.Id;
        }
    }

    public class MapDestination
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public MapDestination Parent { get; set; }
        public List<MapSource> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

A script to populate one:

```
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> Source
    {
        get
        {
            var src = new MapSource
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Parent = new MapSource
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
                    Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
                }
            };
            src.Children = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new MapSource
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
            }).ToList();

            return new [] { new object[] { src }};
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.expressmapper.org/#tutorial

Comment: It sounds like the object is 'not' null but some of the properties in the object are not null.  When you have an object with lots of properties often not all the properties are used (some can be null).  This is very common.

Comment: Actually I'm now convinced current version of ExpressMapper is bugged when you use "map to destination".

Comment: It happens when you have something like a list of "containing class" which I guess causes some not properly handled recursion resolving.

Comment: @SergeAdneom - what version are you using? Could you post some example code? Please see the example that I've tried to recreate : https://dotnetfiddle.net/vB92vM. It seems to me complex objects and collections are working fine. Please let me know if I misunderstood something.

Comment: 1.8.1, I added some code in this post so you can see by yourself. Btw: I discovered the hard way Dictionnary aren't supported (yet). Too bad itsn't not mentioned on the project homepage.