# Can XUnit interfere with the code?

Tags: xunit

I recently have a very weird behaviour, so weird I'm starting to wonder if the culprit could be the unit framework I'm using (XUnit). I asked a question about it there: [Can Expressmapper copy to destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545384/can-expressmapper-copy-to-destination) but this one is no longer about Expressmapper but about XUnit.

Do you know if in some way XUnit can intefere with the code?

Here's a the reason I'm asking:

I can run those 'together or separatly) in any order and I always get this crazy behaviour:

- First test fails (Test_xxx)
- Second test pass (Test_Map)

Both tests contain the very same code!!

```
    [Fact]
    [Trait("Test kind", "Integration")]
    public void Test_xxx()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mapper = new MappingServiceProvider();
        mapper.Register<MapSource, MapDestination>();
        var src = new MapSource
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Parent = new MapSource
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
            }
        };
        src.Children = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new MapSource
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
        }).ToList();
        var dst = new MapDestination();

        // Act
        mapper.Map(src, dst);

        // Assert
        var compare = new CompareLogic(new ComparisonConfig
        {
            IgnoreObjectTypes = true
        });
        var comparison = compare.Compare(src, dst);
        Assert.Equal(new List<Difference>(), comparison.Differences);
    }

    [Fact]
    [Trait("Test kind", "Integration")]
    public void Test_Map()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mapper = new MappingServiceProvider();
        mapper.Register<MapSource, MapDestination>();
        var src = new MapSource
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Parent = new MapSource
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
            }
        };
        src.Children = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new MapSource
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode(),
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
        }).ToList();
        var dst = new MapDestination();

        // Act
        mapper.Map(src, dst);

        // Assert
        var compare = new CompareLogic(new ComparisonConfig
        {
            IgnoreObjectTypes = true
        });
        var comparison = compare.Compare(src, dst);
        Assert.Equal(new List<Difference>(), comparison.Differences);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another method called Test_Map (with a different signature; aka overload).

I guess XUnit requires method name to be unique (something I intended to do).